# Does upgrading Beats and index templates affect old data in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-beats

does updating beats from 6.x version to 7.x version and consequently updating elastic search index template, affects old data in elastic search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Index templates are only applied at index creation and don't affect existing indices.